# Binding events with setTimeout to create custom asynchronous callbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, settimeout

Spent time reading the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron) which helped me understand the asynchronous nature of JavaScript a little better. I'm still getting my feet wet. I'm trying to create my own callbacks by bindings `setTimeouts` to different events. Specifically `change` and `click`. I'm clearly missing something. When I select a year, I get below error in the console. Any help? Thanks!

html

```
<select id="select_year">
<option value="2021">2021</option>
<option value="2022">2022</option>
<option value="2023">2023</option>
</select>
```

js

```
function selectYear(selectedYear) {

$(document).on('change','#select_year',setTimeout(function() {

selectedYear = $(this).val();

}, 0),

)}


selectYear(function(year) {
console.log(year);
});
```

error in console

```
Uncaught TypeError: t.nodeName is undefined
    val jQuery
    selectYear http://localhost:8080/js/calendar.js:20
    setTimeout handler*selectYear http://localhost:8080/js/calendar.js:18
    <anonymous> http://localhost:8080/js/calendar.js:25
jquery.min.js:2:69132
    val jQuery
    selectYear http://localhost:8080/js/calendar.js:20
    (Async: setTimeout handler)
    selectYear http://localhost:8080/js/calendar.js:18
    <anonymous> http://localhost:8080/js/calendar.js:25
```

Comment: I think you need to do `$(document).on('change','#select_year',function() {var $this = ${this);setTimeout(function() {/* code - $this is the element */}, 0);});`, Plus - your argument to the function `selectYear` seems to be the year rather than a function callback, but it is used as both in a very piacular way.

Comment: It's really not clear why you're using `setTimeout` here. Could you clarify?

Comment: @jeff_mcmahan: I'm not trying to call it inside the function. I need to pass the result to an external function to use the variable elsewhere in my codes. Inside the function this is easy. Now outside is the trick.

Comment: @HagaiWild: sir, could you post a full answer? I think that's it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you're doing here does not require a `setTimeout`. Event-driven programming is asynchronous by its nature to begin with. Try this:

```js
'use strict'

const selectYear = year => {
  alert(year);
}

$('#select_year').on('change', function () {
    // This is your callback.
    let selectedYear = $(this).val();
    selectYear(selectedYear);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select_year">
  <option value="2021">2021</option>
  <option value="2022">2022</option>
  <option value="2023">2023</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm clearly missing something.

**True!** And I would even say *many things*.

When talking about `asynchrounous` functions, we usually refer to function calls that resolve in a later time, not blocking the rest of a script execution. Look for [promise](https://javascript.info/promise-basics) if that is what you wish to understand.

What you do wrong in the provided code:

jQuery `.on()` is an event handler method. You can pass 3 arguments:

- event (mandatory)
- delegated selector (optionnal)
- callback (mandatory)

In this case, the callback is a function that is getting executed when an event fires. That isn't the same as an `asynchonous` function. [What is an event?](https://learn.jquery.com/events/introduction-to-events/)

With your attempt, you did not pass a function expression or a function reference... but a function **call**. if you want a `setTimeout` to be exectuted when an event fires, you have to put it inside a function statement like below:

```
$(document).on('change','#select_year', function(){

  let selectedYear = $(this).val();
  
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(selectedYear);
  }, 2000);  // Try with 2 seconds to see the effect!
  
})
```

So the 3rd argument is a function statement... Stored for later execution. If that isn't clear, [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions) is the reading you need.

Another thing... The second argument of `setTimeout()` is a required number. You used zero. That may be correct in some context, but not here. You should use a number for how many milliseconds of delay you want before the 1st argument (which, by the way, is a callback) executes.

Comment: No this doesn't solve my problem. I tried your way before posting here as well. It would have been so easy. Your codes give me same error. Thanks for trying.

Comment: Right... I edited. I went to fast on this one. That is about `this` context... Another thing with a lot of reading to make... An common mistake in JS. I think I gave a lot of starters to you to learn more.